# Azure's Event grid 's reply policy doesn't appear to be working

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I've been trying to implement event propagation through event grid with webhooks for the past week and I've ran into a problem where, even if the subscriber returns an error code which should trigger a retry (any of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#failure-codes), but it just doesn't happen. [image: In this picture] the retry policy configuration is displayed. The server currently always responds with a 503, which should, in theory, mark the events as failed to deliver [image: but it doesn't happen.]. Is there something I am missing?

Oh, and I should probably mention that I'm logging all the events and the events are coming through just once.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example for testing a retry policy with a dead-lettering option. All features works very well.

1. I have a custom topic *(topicTester100)* for firing an event

   ```csharp
    [
      {
        "topic":null,
        "id":"690bb0ec-7aad-4ed9-a7a1-3b6c8899c57c",
        "subject":"/myapp/vehicles/motorcycles",
        "eventType":"retrytest",
        "eventTime":"2020-12-03T14:15:46.660",
        "data":{
          "make":"Ducati",
          "model":"Monster"
        }
      }
    ]
   ```
2. There is a subscription *(Tester--17158468)* on this topic with the following properties:

   ```csharp
   {
    "name":"Tester--17158468",
    "type":"Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions",
    "id":"/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/testerTopic100/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/Tester--17158468",
    "properties":{
      "topic":"/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/microsoft.eventgrid/topics/testertopic100",
      "provisioningState":"Succeeded",
      "destination":{
        "properties":{
          "endpointUrl":null,
          "endpointBaseUrl":"https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpEventGrid",
          "maxEventsPerBatch":1,
          "preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes":64
        },
        "endpointType":"WebHook"
      },
      "filter":{
        "subjectBeginsWith":"",
        "subjectEndsWith":""
      },
      "labels":[
        ""
      ],
      "eventDeliverySchema":"EventGridSchema",
      "retryPolicy":{
        "maxDeliveryAttempts":4,
        "eventTimeToLiveInMinutes":20
      },
      "deadLetterDestination":{
        "properties":{
          "resourceId":"/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/rk2018ebstg",
          "blobContainerName":"eventgrid"
        },
        "endpointType":"StorageBlob"
      }
    }
    }
   ```

   Note, that the *delivery counter = 4* and *TTL = 20 minutes.*
3. The subscriber is implemented as a HttpTrigger function, where the logic for *Notification* messages is the following:

   ```csharp
    else if(eventTypeHeader == "Notification") 
    {   
        log.LogInformation($"Notification message: [id = {jtoken["id"]}, eventType = {jtoken["eventType"]}]");

        return jtoken["eventType"].Value<string>() == "retrytest" ? (ActionResult)new StatusCodeResult(503) : (ActionResult)new OkResult();
    }
   ```

   As you can see the above code snippet, if the *eventType* has a value *retryTest*, the subscriber will returned a status code = *503*, othervise the return code is *200*.
4. The following screen snippet shows the subscriber Logs messages:

   [image]

   As you can see the above Logs, the event message *(id=690bb0ec-7aad-4ed9-a7a1-3b6c8899c57c)* has been delivered three times, the first one is delivered immediately, the second one after 1 minute and the last one such as the third one after 10 minutes. Next delivery has been scheduled after 60 minutes, but this delivery is over the specific time TTL in the subscription such as 20 minutes, therefore the message can be either dropped or if we have a dead-lettering option turned on, the message is sent after 5 minutes (not configurable) to the blob storage, see the following screen snippet:

   [image]

   Note, that there is one more subscription *(TESTER--169394031)* subscribed on the storage account with the same weebhook endpoint as the first one, that's why we can see in the Logs the event based on the storing a dead-lettering message in the blob storage.
5. The following screen snippet shows a dead-lettering message:

   [image]

   As you can see, there is an original event message with the details why the delivery  failed.